# Select Where clause

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a Select in SQL Server and say my Select is pulling the data like this,

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1   xx   xx   xx   xx
2   null null null null
3   xx   xx   null null
```

I only want the records where not all the rows are Null.  In above record, I don't want the row where ID= 2.

How can I do this in where clause?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried "select ... where (col1 is not null and .... )" ?

Answer (score 5):

Do they all have the same datatype? If so

```
WHERE COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This solution forces a full table scan. A computed result of columns in the *WHERE* clause is normally not best practice. There are a few exceptions - but this is not one of them

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Having four `or`-ed `Is Not Null` conditions is extremely likely to end up with a scan too. There are very few cases where the data distribution and available indexes will mean a better plan is possible than just scanning the whole thing for this

Comment: possibly, but the calculation will also make the query slower. 2 of the other answers doesn't make this calculation

Comment: the optimal performance solution would be a computed persisted column - an index could be applied to this column if needed

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - from a performance tuning POV the impact of "the calculation" will be non existent or not worth worrying about. There will **always** be much bigger bang for your buck solving bigger issues than worrying about whether or not CPU time for `COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) IS NOT NULL` is less or more than `Col1 Is Not Null
    Or Col2 Is Not Null
    Or Col3 Is Not Null
    Or Col4 Is Not Null` - computed column could help though if the SELECT is run frequently enough to justify the maintenance (doesn't have to be marked `PERSISTED` to index it here)

Answer (score 3):

An alternate to Martin's solution:

```
Where Col1 Is Not Null
    Or Col2 Is Not Null
    Or Col3 Is Not Null
    Or Col4 Is Not Null
```

It should be noted that if any of the columns are not implicitly castable to the same datatype (e.g. all varchar or all ints), that COALESCE will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where not ( Col1 Is Null
    And Col2 Is Null
    And Col3 Is Null
    And Col4 Is Null)
```

This will make sure that all the columns are not null

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
from table
where Col1>''
and Col2>''
and Col3>''
and Col4>''
```

What this does is it selects all rows that actually have data in them.  However, if you have char fields that are balnk but not null that you need to select, you'll have to change this to >=.  This query will also utalize a covering index i believe.